# Microsoft StreamInsight

Tags: streaminsight

I am looking for some possible options for streaming all changes happening on DB level using Microsoft StreamInsight. One possible way is using DB Triggers (which I don't thing is a good way). If anyone has some experience with this please suggest.

I am open to other products as well, what I really want to do is monitor data changes and raise corresponding events against them. Any help will be appreciated :)

Looking from the comments following details might help:
We have an information system with few components written in C++, few in PowerBuilder, rest all in C#. They all sit on top of common database. In short, we don't have single entry point to database. What we are looking into right now is to add configurable rules which get fired based on Events. This can be easily achieved using 3rd party rules engine. Our only challenge right now is how to generate these events based on change of data. I read about 2 options from SQL Server side:
Change Tracking 
Change Data Capture 
not sure even that can help. I was also trying to see how StreamInsight can help us achieve this. I hope this added more clarity to question.

Comment: All data changes or just ones that meet a threshold?  For every table or a particular subset? When the data changes, are you looking to audit that the event occurred or are you looking to prevent it?  What's the estimate change pattern (lots of one-off insert/updates, big bulk inserts, something else?)

Answer (score 1):

What is the reasoning for this type of audit (compliance?)? And what are you monitoring? In general, I would state this is a buy versus build decision and I would favor buy, but that depends on what changes you are monitoring and why.

If this is a compliance business requirement, I would be even more inclined to use a third party tool that handles compliance, as you have someone else worried about the exceptional cases.

Unless the need is something I am not envisioning, I see StreamInsight as a hammer and you are searching for nails. I.E. I don't think I would head that direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that StreamInsight is the right solution for what you are trying to do. It is really good at in-memory processing of high volumes of data within a temporal context. Once you get a disk involved (which you are with a database), your latency skyrockets. 
Question: What is the business problem that you are trying to solve? What are your key use cases?